# Using vb.net to convert US to GB date time and returning data

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, date

this is what I have:

```
Dim UsDateFormat As Date = DateTime.Parse(DataDate, New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")) 

Da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM RawStockData WHERE PointDateTime >=#" & UsDateFormat.ToShortDateString & "# AND PointDateTime < #" & UsDateFormat.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString & "#", Con)
```

When selecting any date in september, it'll show the data for the 30th (which is the only day with data), and when selecting the 30th, it'll reply with "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it was messy, I used

```
 Da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM RawStockData WHERE PointDateTime >=#" & DataDate.Date.Month.ToString & "/" & DataDate.Date.Day.ToString & "/" & DataDate.Date.Year.ToString & "# AND PointDateTime <#" & DataDate.AddDays(1).Date.Month.ToString & "/" & DataDate.AddDays(1).Date.Day.ToString & "/" & DataDate.AddDays(1).Date.Year.ToString & "#", Con)
```

in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Where you use .ToShortDateString, replace it with .ToString("yy-MM-dd")

For ms sql at least, this is a safe date format to use regardless of culture and is always interpreted correctly.

EDIT:
If you really want the format you ended up using, just use .ToString("MM/dd/yy")

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem will be resolved using [DataTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

After try ParseExact, please use [SqlCommand Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) to avoid every SQL errors with Date and DateTime.

Sample code:

```
Dim strYourData As String = "2013/10/02"
Dim dtYourData As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(strYourData, "yyyy/MM/dd", Nothing)

Dim cmdSelectRawStockData As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand = yourOLEConnection.CreateCommand
cmdSelectRawStockData.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM RawStockData WHERE " _
    & "PointDateTime >= @YourData1 AND " _
    & "PointDateTime <= @YourData2"

cmdSelectRawStockData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YourData1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtYourData
cmdSelectRawStockData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YourData2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, dtYourData)

Da = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSelectRawStockData)
```

Answer (score 0):

USE below code and vice vera

```
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(InputBookingdatesingleday.Text,
                                         "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                         CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"))

Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(InputBookingdatesingleday.Text,
                                         "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                         CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Comment: InputBookingdatesingleday and CultureInfo aren't declared, I swear I saw this exact code in another stackoverflow question?